# communication between two subnet masks

Tags: networking, subnet

this may be a silly question. i have created a subnet on my network of 10.55.0.0/21. 
the network already had a subnet of 10.55.1.0/24.

My question is why can a /21 address communicate with a /24 address and vice versa?

regards,

DPERROTT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/21` network *includes* the `/24` network. If you want them to be separate and want to route between them, create non-overlapping subnets, say make the new one `10.55.2/24`.